# Login not working in IE11 .But working properly on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: c++, session-cookies

There is a C++ firmware code which is used to set cookie to a browser as follows

```
sprintf(szTmp, "Set-Cookie: CGISESSID=%s; language=en; Max-Age=%d; Version=1; expires=%s; path=/", m_szSid, p_unCookieLifetime, outstr);

fprintf( io.output, "%s\r\n", szTmp );
```

The cookie goes to the output stream and gets set in the IE-11 but when I try to retrieve the cookie back using the name "CGISESSID" then NULL is returned.From this I understand that IE11 is not storing the cookie so is there any way to resolve this. 
I tried the following way:
Go to Settings->Internet Options-> Privacy and selected Accept all cookies but still its not working .

Actually I am setting this cookie for login purpose.
Please let me know if anyone can help.

Regards,
Sid

Comment: I am also having similar issues